# Is there a helper method for pluralization in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def plural(value, string)
  "#{value} #{value.abs == 1 ? string.singularize : string.pluralize}"
end
```

If not, what would be a short, sweet name for this method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

```
  pluralize(1, 'person')
  # => 1 person

  pluralize(2, 'person')
  # => 2 people
```

More documentation and examples available [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)